# iOS: Gesture on child view not recognized

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a UIScrollView as my root view, and a UIImageView (let's call it parent view) as a subview of the root view. Then I add another UIImageView (lat's call it child view) as subview of the parent view. The child view is not contained in the parent view's bounds. This is the visual representation of my view layout.

```
................................
.       root view              .
.                  .........   .
.  ..............  . child .   .
.  .parent view .  . view  .   .
.  ..............  .........   .
.                              .
................................
```

Now when I add a UIPanGestureRecognizer to the child view, the gesture is not recognized. I've checked userInteractionEnabled and everything. When I set the child view as a subview of the root view, the gesture is recognized correctly. Does anyone know what causes this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this problem is caused because you've added a `UIGestureRecognizer` to something that isn't visible in its parents bounds. If you set `clipsToBounds = YES` on *parentView*, the *childView* isn't shown, right? That's the way it is treated. You may see it, but "it isn't there".

**It's like this**: You're in the kitchen, you can hear the TV in the living room and you **know** it's there, but you can't see it. If the walls were invisible on the other hand, you could see it, but you can't interact with it. Because you can't walk through walls.

Hopes this is to any help.

Comment: That's what I think also. But I need the child view to be attached to the parent view so that they can be moved together. Is there any way to achieve this without using subview?

Comment: You could use a UIView as a parent view and add both images in to this one and attach the GestureRecognizer to the UIView instead of one of the images. This will make both of em move when you move the large view.

Comment: I accept this as the answer for my question. This will be helpful for other iOS programmers since it's not very common to encounter this kind of situation.

Answer (score 0):

Set `tag` for your childview :

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
          initWithTarget:self
                  action:@selector(singleTapGestureCaptured:)];
[[rootview viewWithTag:111]addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

-(void)singleTapGestureCaptured:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture 
{
    //your code;
}
```

Comment: I've already added the UIGestureRecognizer to my child view. The problem is that the gesture is not recognized, i.e. the view does not respond to tapping, panning, etc

Comment: I tried it and you are right Ryan, it doesn't work. You should resize your parentview when you add subviews. You will probably have to override the sizeThatFits method.